# VS code does not see the interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, odoo

I am learning odoo development following Greg Moss tutorial. I successfully set up the virtual environment and install all the necessary files. However VS Code doesn't recognizer the python interpreter. I checked into the bin folder in my virtual environment to see if the interpreter was there was installed and sure enough it was. I don't understand why VS Code can't see it. Can someone help me see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are using Linux, isn't it? Could you provide some screenshots of it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you select the interpreter for VSCode?
You can config this way: Open Command Palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P`) and type `Python: Select Interpreter` then click **Enter interpreter path**... and choose your venv python path (example: /opt/openerp/.local/share/virtualenvs/odoo14/bin/python)

Comment: yes i did try to select the interpreter through the command palette and I used a path similar to what you gave, but VS Code does not recognize the interpreter in the bin folder; in fact it is not visible as an executable. I first thought that it wasn't installed but using the file explorer, I found it is at its right place in the bin folder.

Comment: Can you start odoo-bin with that interpreter normally?

Comment: I can start odoo from the terminal. But I can't from VS code

Comment: Can you show me your interpreter path that you used in VS Code and all the commands that you used to run Odoo on terminal?

Comment: Hi Randy. Sorry I was away. Here is the error I get when I select the interpreter

Unable to open 'python': Unable to read file '\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\opt\odoo13\odoo-venv\bin\python' (Unknown (FileSystemError): Error: ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, open '\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\opt\odoo13\odoo-venv\bin\python').